# How to convert spring batch jar to deployable war on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a working set of spring batch jar's that work independently well.
But now there is requirement to deploy them as war to tomcat.

Please suggest some link or logic from where I can take it ahead.

So far what I have tried did not work. i.e. just converted jar to war. but it does not work. the job is not triggered.

Please suggest.

Comment: How do you trigger your jobs?

Comment: I trigger the job from a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the packaging from jar to war, created a webApp folder in it.
Added web.xml and dispatchedServlet.xml in it. The dispatcher servlets gets loaded from web.xml on load and initiates the listneners to the queue.

Works perfectly for me.